# Accessing value from resource file inside App_LocalResources to razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, localization

Can I access a value from resource file inside App_LocalResources folder to the Razor view?

Resources files inside App_GlobalResources folder can be accessed as follows.

```
<span>@Resources.MyResource.TestMessage</span>
```

Is there any similar way to access file inside App_LocalResources. If not what is the best way to get a value to the Razor View?